# MySQL int() without limit

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySQL together with PHP to create a login system.
Every time a new user register, i have a 'int' variable called ID, which uses PRIMARY KEY and AUTO_INCREMENT to increase with 1 every time. Though, there seems to be a limit of int(), which I don't want. Please help.

```
id int() not null AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
```

Comment: What is the "limit of `int()`"? All numerical columns have limits, `INT` is no different, but unless you're registering thousands of users per second you should not have a problem.

Comment: Unsigned int has a max value of 4294967295

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text**.

Comment: `bigint()` ? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html

Comment: @JazZ That has a limit, too. They all have limits.

Comment: @tadman sure, there's always a limit.

Comment: @JazZ Obviously, but Melvin seems to want a column with no limit, which is something that doesn't exist.

Comment: With a BIGINT column auto incrementing by 1, you should never hit the max value of 18446744073709551615.  If you do, you shouldn't be designing databases

Comment: @tadman Yes, he's looking for something impossible. I just share the biggest integer storage type I know and link to documentation.

Comment: Whilst I agree with @tadman et al, I suppose one could use `LONGBLOB` to store the binary representation of an identifier up to 2^32 bytes in length, i.e. capable of representing 8^(2^32)—which is a number that is approximately **100 billion** digits in length!  I doubt anyone could *ever* need an identifier that large.  `BIGINT UNSIGNED` is capable of representing 2^64 (about 18 quintillion) identifiers, which can represent the entire population of planet Earth more than 2.5 billion times over.

Comment: @eggyal Still technically limited even if the limit is ridiculously high.

Comment: @eggyal `LONGBLOB` can't be defined as primary key. But `VARBINARY(255)` might be enough to register every atom in the universe :-) Though it doesn't work with `AUTO_INCREMENT` - So a trigger would be required :-))

Answer (score 0):

The maximum value pf the INT type is 2^31-1 signed and 2^32-1 unsigned. Or in simple words, it is 32 bit wide. If you need a larger INT type you must use BIGINT which is 64 bit wide.
For further information take a look into the MySQL documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html